# How to attach file to SharePoint Form

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are creating a work flow using fillable PDF forms. Policy requires a copy of an invoice or receipt be attached to every payment request.  Is there a way to attach an external file (invoice) to the Sharepoint form?

Comment: Where are you storing these files.. I mean once a user fills in the PDF and save what happens?

Answer (score 3):

From the list form ribbon, you can attach an item.

[image: Attach Item]